# Problem with water rushing through whole house humidifier

Tags: hvac, humidifier

I have a Honeywell Enviracaire Elite whole house humidifier Model HE365A1006 connected to my HVAC system. When the furnace runs, the water is rushing straight through the middle of the water panel filter, rather than flowing across the water distribution tray to spread across the whole filter. As a result, it really isn’t humidifying and is just wasting a lot of water. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It would be helpful to edit your question to add the model number of the humidifier.

Comment: Have you taken the covers off the humidifier to look to see if anything looks to be out of the ordinary? Anything that's obviously out of place? Maybe take a pic or two and edit them into your post so others can take a look, too. Someone may spot something you haven't seen.

Answer (score 2):

In my humidifier the pan on top of the filter is a piece of rubbery flexible plastic that needs the filter intact to be flat and level to allow the water to flow out and run down the little holes.  Check that the top is level, the sides are plumb, and the holes in the pan are not blocked by lime, dust, or whatever.

I recall that the filter needs to be installed right side up, the top marked by a red dot, to work properly.  Check that the filter is right side up.  I don't know if all humidifiers use the same kind of filter that needs to be installed in a certain orientation but it's a place to start.

These filters do need replacement over time as they fill up with lime and dust, maybe you need a new filter.  If it's been damaged, causing the frame to be out of plumb and level, then it definitely needs replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Check and see if the feed tube nozzle is cracked or not connected properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends; it may be designed to work that way, possible water flow can be adjusted. Most humidifiers are "dead ends", the water goes in and evaporates. This leaves an amazing amount of dissolved mineral build-up in a cold climate. This require changing pads and  significant annual cleaning. To avoid this, some humidifiers have a continuous small water flow. Some water evaporates but the remaining water carries the concentrated mineral away to a drain so there is (ideally) no mineral build up in the humidifier. I expect your humidifier is the latter type.